# Slim Framework member function render() on a non-object

Tags: php, slim

Hey So I'm setting up some classes to keep my Routes out of the eye of my index.php,

**index.php**

```
require 'library/Slim/Slim.php';

$app=new Slim();
$app->map('/api/:class/:method(/:args1(/:args2(/:args3)))', function ($class,$method) use ($app) {

    $args=array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);
    require_once('library/controllers/'.str_replace('.','/',$class).'.php');

        $Class=substr($class,strrpos($class,'.'));
        $controller=new $Class($app);

        if(method_exists($controller,$method)) $controller->{$method}($args);

})->via('GET', 'POST');

$app->run();
```

And am calling something like this
__http://domain.com/api/photos/recent/args/args/args

**Test Class Photos**

```
<?php

class photos {

    private $app;

    public function __contruct() {
        $this->app = Slim::getInstance();
    }

    public function recent() {

        $this->app->render('test.html');

    }

}
```

And am just trying to run an instance of Slim to render, but am not getting it for some reason? Test HTML is in the same dir as photos.php

What am I doing wrong? I'm dying with fatal error

**PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function render() on a non-object in /library/controllers/photos.php on line 13**

Comment: did you checked if the $this->App got and instance? (try with var_dump($this->app) and check if it's not null

Comment: Returns bool true, so it IS working. Good clarification question btw, +1

Comment: Sorry I had a var_export preceding it, it is **bool false**

Comment: The answer: I can't spell for shi* on Mondays. I its `__construct()` not `__contruct()` ;)